# Selectively Export SVN Directory

Tags: svn, export

Is it possible to export an SVN directory while ignoring certain file extensions?  (Say, `.cpp`?)

I need to export my header files, which contain my library's symbols, to some other folder where I'll zip them up along with the finished static/dynamic library products.  Normally I'd just move the header files up a level in the directory and use the `--depth` option, but a few of the headers `#include` other required headers deeper in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to selectively export a directory, but what you *can* do is export it normally and then run the following on the new directory:

```
find NewDirectory -name \*.Extension -delete
```

This will remove all `*.Extension` files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export svn repository
2. Go to the exported directory
3. Run from command line (to copy *.h files only):

`find . -name \*.h -print | xargs cp -t pathToYourDestinationDir/`

I tested to .php files:

`find . -name \*.php -print | xargs cp -t ../test2/`

Comment: I got it to work, but there's a simpler way: `find ExportedDirectory -name \*.cpp -delete`